# Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I would like to know whether the Facebook PHP SDK is up to date with regards to Facebooks Server Side Authentication (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

I am having difficulty obtaining an access_token when FB passes back my state and code.
Am I meant to programmatically add this functionality? Or is the SDK meant to handle the response from Facebook?

example:

I pass FB:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&state=ef8dba2dc8b4fa002973ffa5e29c67cb
```

Facebook returns:

```
http://localhost/?state=ef8dba2dc8b4fa002973ffa5e29c67cb&code=AQAhuVUqufbghj2bBLcCr5SdRJopdYaR-vAoZJzilvvDgiGYNuEPVKTRLqD9p9MPrPhIIubYPH0aka8RtBQU_vSGdkCI5DkQxhQpwWcADu1_jSQgOC9vBsF2oWardpcPcq4PzmNq-JYhdvEFyMD0K7vPY0WioUgLghhw28FJAhHis9K7dz6HyrNy0YXfjbK0AN0#_=_
```

However the SDK does not handle this response above from Facebook.
Facebook suggests you obtain and access token by passing back the code.

1. Exchange the code for a user access token

Once the user has authorized your app, you should make a server side request to exchange the code returned above for a user access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

Does the SDK not do this itself?

Comment: I think to get an access token you need to be signed in and follow the trail of auth dialogues to give the app your making the appropriate permissions but you can also use the graph api explorer and give yourself an access token if you just need it for development purposes - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(

          'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream,publish_actions',

          'redirect_uri' => 'login.php', //give ur apropriate page

    ));


if($user){

    $acestokn = $facebook -> getaccesstoken();

}else{

    header('location:'.$url);
           exit;
}
```